# Horovod and Tensorflow estimators

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can I extend the [Horovod](https://github.com/uber/horovod) example that uses `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` to instead use `tf.estimator.Estimator`? I am using Tensorflow 1.4.0.

[Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/peterroelants/9956ec93a07ca4e9ba5bc415b014bcca) that closely resembles my current code.

I want to use this together with `hyperopt`, and I like how I can easily do something like

```
tf.contrib.learn.learn_runner.run(
      experiment_fn=_create_my_experiment,
      run_config=run_config,
      schedule="train_and_evaluate",
      hparams=hparams)
```

to train with different hyperparameters, `hparams`. This also gives me separate Tensorboard log directories for training and validation sets - and I'd like this to be true with a Horovod solution as well. I played around with a  `tf.train.SingularMonitoredSession(hooks=hooks, config=config)` where `hooks` contains a `tf.train.SummarySaverHook`, but I only could make it work nicely with the training set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [TensorFlow Estimator example](https://github.com/uber/horovod/blob/master/examples/tensorflow_mnist_estimator.py) has been added to the Horovod repo.